# Google Map slow after displaying a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am displaying various fragments in an Activity FrameLayout.  The first fragment I display is a Google Map. To display a fragment, I swap the FrameLayout with a fragment.  Next I display a fragment then push to the backstack.  Upon popping the backstack the Google Map becomes very slow and laggy.  If I override onBackPressed, remove the pushed fragment from the backstack then recreate the Google Map fragment, the Google Map responds as expected.  Overridding onBackPressed seems like a work around.

How come the map is slow and laggy?

Here is my code (without the onBackPressed function I mentioned):

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        displayFragment(new MapFragment());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        try {
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if(id == R.id.displayBlankFragment) {
                displayDialogFragment(new BlankFragment());
                return true;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void displayFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        t.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
        t.commit();
    }

    private void displayDialogFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        t.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
        t.addToBackStack(null);
        t.commit();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MapFragment**

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;

    public MapFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

**fragment_map.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" >
    </fragment>

</FrameLayout>
```

**BlankFragment**

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    public BlankFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }
}
```

**fragment_blank.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Are you reloading the map fragment?

Comment: The map fragment is not reloaded.  When the user presses the back button from the BlankFragment, the Android framework automatically displays the MapFragment.